# convert the date while import data from excel sheet to the database in php

Tags: php

Im having a excel sheet with the format 10/12/2012.then i convert it into csv file i have a date as "41253",When i import that into my database it is storing as 0000-00-00. How to convert the date format while importing. or is there any other way?.

This is the code im using to import to database

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

GLOBAL $HTTP_POST_FILES;

//$path= $HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'];
$path= $_FILES['ufile']['name'];
//
if(copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $path))
{

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="xyz"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="productsegmentmaster"; // Table name 
require_once '.\phpExcelReader\Excel\reader.php';
$excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$excel->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$excel->read($path);
$x=2;
$sep = "*";
ob_start();
while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) {
$y=1;
$row="";
while($y<=$excel->sheets[0]['numCols']) {
$cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
$row.=($row=="")?"".$cell."":"".$sep."".$cell."";
$y++;
} 
echo $row."\n"; 
$x++;
}
    //echo "Sheet count:$x";
$fp = fopen("data.csv",'w');
fwrite($fp,ob_get_contents());
fclose($fp);
//echo"----";   
ob_end_clean();
//connect to the database 
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("AmaraRaja",$connect); //select the table 
//$file = $_FILES['data.csv']['tmp_name']; 
$handle = fopen('data.csv',"r"); 
//loop through the csv file and insert into database 
global $data;
do { 
//echo "$data[0]";
//echo "$data[1]";
//echo "$data[2]";
        //$post['ProductSegmentCode'] = $data[0];
//      $post['ProductSegment'] = $data[1];
//           $post['ProductGroup'] = $data[2];
         $post['ProductCode'] = $data[0];
        $post['WarrantyPeriod'] = $data[1];
        $post['ProRataPeriod'] = $data[2];
        $test = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($data[3]));
        $post['ManufactureDate'] = $test;
       $test1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($data[4]));
       echo  $data[4];
        $post['ApplicableFormDate'] = $test1;
         $tname = "productwarranty";
try
{
 if($data[0]!="")
 {
     $news->addNews($post,$tname);
//mysql_query("INSERT INTO productsegmentmaster VALUES ( '$data[0]', '$data[1]','$data[2]')"); 

  }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e.getMessage();
}
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,"*","'")); 
echo"<script>alert('File $path Imported Successfully')</script>";
}
fclose($handle);

unlink('data.csv');
unlink($path);
}

?>
```

Comment: format the date field in Excel to text before switching to CSV.

Comment: i already have a lot of entries in that date field , if i change it all dates are changed to numeric values...

Comment: =TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")  << run that formula on all the dates to a new field before saving as CSV, that converts them to text in the correct format.

Comment: please give us an example row of your csv file. nobody knows how $data[4] looks like.

Comment: i already mentioned in the top, any how $data[4] contains a date value like 41253.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I have the same exact problem! I tried the format way, didn't work!

I don't know if it's applicable to you, but a solution that I came with was put a apostrophe in front of it! ('YYYY/mm/dd). The Excel itself omit the apostrophe and only show data AS TEXT, not as a Excel timestamp. In that way you can explode the data by "/" and put it in the way you want.

BUT, if is impossible to you put a apostrophe in front in every one of them, you can verifiy if is a number and try to [convert the excel timestamp to unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703505/excel-date-to-unix-timestamp), assuming you server a *NIX like.

=)

I know it isn't the best solution, but so far is what I can get. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    $date_format = floor($excelDateTime);
    $time_format = $excelDateTime - $date_format;
    $mysql_strdate = ($date_format > 0) ? ( $date_format - 25569 ) * 86400 + $time_format * 86400 :    $time_format * 86400;
    $mysql_date_format = date("Y-d-m", $mysql_strdate);
```