# How to convert excel date to timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, datetime, xlsx

I got array of dates from excel file and they look like strange fractional numbers: 42425.4166550926, 42419.3326041667, 42411.5419097222, etc. How to convert them to unix timestamp or javascript date?

Comment: Without more information it will be very difficult to provide an answer. Where did these timestamps get generated? Do you know what the resulting date *should* be?

Comment: Does anything [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/664812-visual-basic-applications-convert-timestamp.html) help? What have you tried?

Comment: I think this is excel raw date format. LibreOffice Calc gives the same numbers with "@" cell formatting. As for resulting values - yes, I know them: 42379.4806597222 is 01/10/2016 11:32:09 for example. As a last resort I could just format all collumns as text in xlsx file and parse it again, but I wonder is there other way around.

Comment: for a js solution, there is a conversion function for that posted by someone [on gist](https://gist.github.com/christopherscott/2782634)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert date to timestamp, a formula can work it out.

Select a blank cell and type this formula `=(A1-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400` into it and press Enter key, if you need, you can apply a range with this formula by dragging the autofill handle. Now a range of date cells have been converted to Unix timestamps.

[image]

[Source](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2473-excel-timestamp-to-date.html)

Another [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703505/excel-date-to-unix-timestamp)...