# How to make equivalent MOD excel function in PHP

Tags: php, excel, date

When I use this function in excel

```
=MOD("06/03/1992";7)
```

it returns 6

How to make the function in PHP?
I try this code in PHP, but the result is different

```
$today = strtotime("06-03-1992");
$mod = ($today/86400) % 7;
echo $mod;
//return 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you calculate with 2 different numbers:

1. Excel converts "1992-06-03" internally into 33'758.
2. `strtotime` returns the UNIX timestamp in seconds; dividing it [as you did] by 86'400 returns 8'188.

As you can see the values don't match.

I refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703505/excel-date-to-unix-timestamp) which describes how to convert an Excel Date to Unix timestamp. This should fix your problem.

Comment: [link](http://fczaja.blogspot.co.id/2011/06/convert-excel-date-into-timestamp.html)

Comment: [fczaja](http://fczaja.blogspot.co.id/2011/06/convert-excel-date-into-timestamp.html)
What is $excelDate format in that article?
Thanks, sorry for comment before