# How do I get a string value of the 5 digit serial date format from a cell into my script?

Tags: string, datetime, serialization, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a formula in a cell that is doing a vlookup to another sheet by combining the values of two cells on my spreadsheet.  It's a table of names on the left and dates up top.  I'm combining the name and date values into a single string value and using that as by vlookup key value, which works great.  Now I need to basically do the same thing in my google script, but the date value has me at a loss.  In the vlookup cell formula, the date value is the 5 digit date serial code.  However when I combine the two cell values in my script, I cannot get the same 5 digit serial code out of the cell.  I have tried all conversions of number, string, text, ect.  What function can I use to get this 5 digit date value as a string in my script?

```
function serialDatevalue(){
  var WB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var NewDate = new Date();
  var NewDate =  WB.getRange('B1').getValue();
  var JSdate =  WB.getRange('B1').getValue();
  Browser.msgBox(Number(NewDate));

// Some others that I have tried
//  var JSdate = Date.parse(DateValue);
//  var JSdate = Number(DateValue);
//  var JSdate = Utilities.formatDate(DateValue, 'PST', '%');
}
```

for example, April 13, 2019 = 43568.  I want to get this 5 digit value as a string.

I keep getting 'Sat Apr 13 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)', or other longer integer values.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

From [Tanaike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741435/1595451) to [Getting the number equalent of duration using GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55740554/1595451)

`var serialNumber = (dateObject.getTime() / 1000 / 86400) + 25569; // Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953`

---

The easier way to get the serialized number corresponding to a certain cell date value in Google Sheets is by using a the built-in Google Sheets function [TO_PURE_NUMBER][1]. This because Google Sheets and JavaScript, which is used by Google Apps Script, used different epoch (reference date used as 0 for the serialized numbers) and use different time units.

From https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#datetime_serial_numbers

> **Date/Time serial numbers**
>
> Google Sheets, like most other spreadsheet
> applications, treats date/time values as decimal values. This lets you
> perform arithmetic on them in formulas, so you can increment days or
> weeks, add or subtract two date/times, and perform other similar
> operations.
>
> Google Sheets uses a form of [epoch date](https://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEpoch_(reference_date)%23Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) that is commonly used in
> spreadsheets. The whole number portion of the value (left of the
> decimal) counts the days since December 30th 1899. The fractional
> portion (right of the decimal) counts the time as a fraction of one
> day. For example, January 1st 1900 at noon would be 2.5, 2 because
> it's two days after December 30th, 1899, and .5 because noon is half a
> day. February 1st 1900 at 3pm would be 33.625.
>
> Note that Google Sheets correctly treats the year 1900 as a common
> year, not a leap year.

By the other hand, JavaScript use January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC as the epoch date and use milliseconds  as the unit.

A word of caution: Custom code to make serialized number conversions from one to the other should consider if the spreadsheet and the Google Apps Script are using the same timezone or not.

Related

- [How to read value of fetched cell data as date google sheets API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42216491/1595451)
- [Getting the number equalent of duration using GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55740554/1595451)

Comment: That function did exactly what I needed.  This function is getting built into a for loop, so I needed the exact 5 digit value of the date to cycle through the selected cells.  Thank you very much, I was stumped.