# How to get AUD price of bitcoin at a particular date

Tags: excel, web-scraping, cryptocurrency

I am trying to find out how to get the price of bitcoin, ethereum, litecoin and bitcoin cash in AUD at a particular date.

I have a table as follows

```
+------------+-------+
|    Date    | Price |
+------------+-------+
| 16/03/2016 |       |
| 19/04/2016 |       |
| 03/12/2017 |       |
+------------+-------+
```

I have tried entering using `=IMPORTXML("http://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/","//span[@id='quote_price']")` in the price column but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you looking to get current time/value or historical?

Comment: Can you provide the sample result situation you expect? I cannot understand about the relationship between your formula and your table. I apologize for this.

Comment: I would not expect it to work since `IMPORTXML` is not an Excel function.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/documentation?key=Historical&cat=dataPriceHistorical

```
In order to use this service you need an api key and register at their website:https://www.cryptocompare.com/cryptopian/api-keys

You also need to convert your date to unix timestamp:
https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php
e.g. 16/03/2016 => 1458086400
so ts=1458086400

The complete api call would resemble:
https://minapi.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistoricalfsym=BTC&tsyms=AUD&ts=%201458086400&api_key="your-key"
```

executing this call gives = AUD: 582.52

[image: This is an example spreadsheet]

The value in 'Kolom1' is de resulting value in AUD. This value can be retrieved by executing the url in 'URL' field : =WEBSERVICE([@URL])

Remark: to convert your dates 16/03/16 see post:
[Excel date to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703505/excel-date-to-unix-timestamp)