# Filter between two data in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got data like this one:
[image]

I want to filter in column G in the way it only shows data between two dates for example between 12/01 and 12/15, this way:

[image]

I manage to create a filter that make it but I am trying to do it via Google App Script.
Here what I tried until now:

```
function CopyData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Histórico");
  const  pasteSheet = ss.insertSheet();

  copySheet.getRange("A:K").copyTo(pasteSheet.getRange("A:K"), {contentsOnly:true});
  copySheet.getRange("A:K").copyTo(pasteSheet.getRange("A:K"), {formatOnly:true});

  const  range = pasteSheet.getRange("A:I");
  const  filter = range.createFilter();
  var date1 = new Date('2021-12-03'); //mm-dd-yyyy
  var date2 = new Date('2021-12-12'); //mm-dd-yyyy
  
  const Filter_Criteria1 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenDateAfter(date1);
  Logger.log(date1);
  

  const Filter_Criteria2 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberBetween(2021-12-01,2021-12-25);

  const coll1 = 7;

  const  add_filter2 =  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(coll1,Filter_Criteria2);
}
```

The problem here is that when I execute it the number format in filter criteria in unformated:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### The `whenNumberBetween()` filter is for numbers

If you want to use it on dates, you need to convert the dates into their equivalent [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en).

You can do it by first getting the [unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) of the date with [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) and then convert it to years and calcualte the [Excel /Sheets date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703505/excel-date-to-unix-timestamp/6154953#6154953).

The result is the number you can use for `whenNumberBetween()`

Sample:

```js
  var date1 = new Date('2021-12-03');
  var date2 = new Date('2021-12-12');
  var number1 = date1.getTime()/1000/86400 + 25569;
  var number2 = date2.getTime()/1000/86400 + 25569;
  const Filter_Criteria2 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberBetween(number1, number2); 
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(coll1, Filter_Criteria2);
```