# Copying a date/time formatted cell, it changes hours or minutes value in the target cell

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please, just to understand where I made a mistake.
I have a spreadsheet called "source_list", there is a single sheet inside. In that sheet the cell R4 is formatted as "dd/mm/yy HH:MM".
Using a script I copy the data from this sheet to spreadsheet "dest_sprd" with various sheets inside,the script copies as well the R4 cell with  the statement:

```
ws.getRange("T1").setValue(wsSrc.getRange("R4").getValue())
```

T1 is a cell with the same format "dd/mm/yy HH:MM".

In the cell T1 I can see that the date is correct but the hour isn't, it differs by about 30 minutes from the R4 cell.
In another case with the same copy statement, but different spreadsheet, the difference is 1 hour.
The workaround I found is to format cell R5 as a plain number and put it "=R4", then the copy statement is

```
ws.getRange("T1").setValue(wsSrc.getRange("R5").getValue())
```

Now I have the correct date and time in cell T1.

Why it happens like that? I missed something?
Thank you for your help.

Edit: I found the problem, the spreadsheets where generated without the timezone info.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your actual situation, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your situation and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

About the following your question,

> Why it happens like that? I missed something?

About `I have a spreadsheet called "source_list", there is a single sheet inside. In that sheet the cell R4 is formatted as "dd/mm/yy HH:MM". Using a script I copy the data from this sheet to spreadsheet "dest_sprd" with various sheets inside,the script copies as well the R4 cell with the statement:`, in your actual situation, if the Spreadsheet including "source_list" sheet is different from the Spreadsheet including "dest_sprd", I guessed that the timezone might be different between these Spreadsheets. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue.

If you want to avoid this issue, how about the following modification patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the same timezone is used in both the Spreadsheet including "source_list" and the Spreadsheet including "dest_sprd".

Unfortunately, I do not know your actual Spreadsheet. So, this script is a simple sample script. Please be careful about this.

In this case, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet including "source_list" sheet.

```js
function sample1() {
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###"); // Please set the Spreadsheet ID of Spreadsheet including "dest_sprd" sheet.
  const wsSrc = ss1.getSheetByName("source_list");
  const ws = ss2.getSheetByName("dest_sprd");

  const ss2Timezone = ss2.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(); // Store current timezone of ss2.
  ss2.setSpreadsheetTimeZone(ss1.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()); // Change timezone of ss2 to the timezone of ss1.
  ws.getRange("T1").setValue(wsSrc.getRange("R4").getValue());
  ss2.setSpreadsheetTimeZone(ss2Timezone); // Change timezone of ss2 to the original timezone of ss2.
}
```

- In this sample script, before the date object is put to the "dest_sprd" sheet of "ss2", the timezone is set to that of "ss1". And, the value is put into the cell "T1". And then, the timezone of "ss2" is changed to the original timezone of "ss2". By this flow, the value can be kept with the original timezone of "ss2".

#### Pattern 2

About `The workaround I found is to format cell R5 as a plain number and put it "=R4", then the copy statement is` in your question, in this case, I guessed that the timezone offset is reflected. When this is used, the sample script is as follows.

Unfortunately, I do not know your actual Spreadsheet. So, this script is a simple sample script. Please be careful about this.

In this case, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet including "source_list" sheet.

```js
function sample2() {
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###"); // Please set the Spreadsheet ID of Spreadsheet including "dest_sprd" sheet.
  const wsSrc = ss1.getSheetByName("source_list");
  const ws = ss2.getSheetByName("dest_sprd");

  const value = wsSrc.getRange("R4").getValue();
  const unixTimeWithOffset = value.getTime() - (1000 * 60 * value.getTimezoneOffset());
  const serialNumber = (unixTimeWithOffset / 1000 / 86400) + 25569; // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953
  ws.getRange("T1").setValue(serialNumber);
}
```

#### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, the timezone of "ss2" is directly set to the date object.

Unfortunately, I do not know your actual Spreadsheet. So, this script is a simple sample script. Please be careful about this.

In this case, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet including "source_list" sheet.

```js
function sample3() {
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###"); // Please set the Spreadsheet ID of Spreadsheet including "dest_sprd" sheet.
  const wsSrc = ss1.getSheetByName("source_list");
  const ws = ss2.getSheetByName("dest_sprd");

  const range = wsSrc.getRange("R4");
  const v = Utilities.parseDate(range.getDisplayValue(), ss2.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), range.getNumberFormat().replace(/"/g, ""));
  ws.getRange("T1").setValue(v);
}
```

#### Note:

- From my guess, I could correctly replicate your situation. And, when I tested the above scripts, I confirmed that both scripts worked. If you tested these scripts, your expected result might not be able to be obtained, can you provide the sample Spreadsheets? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### References:

- [getSpreadsheetTimeZone()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getspreadsheettimezone)
- [getSpreadsheetTimeZone()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getspreadsheettimezone)
- [getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)
- [parseDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsedatedate,-timezone,-format)

Comment: @LUCA DELLA GHEZZA About `Tanaike, thank you so much for taking the time to write your answer, I'll try your patterns as soon as I'll get home. Anyway it's surprising for me that there are different time zones in two spreadsheets that reside in my company drive, they are in different folders, but in the same drive. The spreadsheets are generated by Google system and I I've never changed any parameter.`, if you had commented on my answer, you commented to another user.

Comment: @LUCA DELLA GHEZZA By the way, from your comment, I understood that my guess to your situation was correct. But, if my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your results:

Using this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getRange("A4").setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm")
  sh.getRange("A4").setValue(new Date());
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test1id);
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  dsh.getRange("B4").setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm")
  dsh.getRange("B4").setValue(sh.getRange("A4").getValue())
}
```

I get the same date and time

Comment: Tanaike, thank you so much for taking the time to write your answer, I'll try your patterns as soon as I'll get home. Anyway it's surprising for me that there are different time zones in two spreadsheets that reside in my company drive, they are in different folders, but in the same drive.
The spreadsheets are generated by Google system and I I've never changed any parameter.

Comment: Dear Tanaike, after many trials and google search I found the problem. Your workarounds where goods, but I want to find the solution and I got it. Some spreadsheet of mine, many of them, are generated without the timezone info, it was enough to set the timezone in the spreadsheet and everything was ok. Now the problem should be to understand why Google creates some Spreadsheet with timezone data and others no. But this is out of my capacities.