# Make Button to increase all dates in Column by 1 Google Sheets Apps Script

Tags: javascript, date, range, multiple-columns, spreadsheet

[image]I have a spreadsheet and I need to increase dates in the ranges
'G5:G27','T5:T27','AG5:AG27','AT5:AT27'
by one month. I want to create a button to run this script as i will be copying the sheet and then wish to just press the button to update all the dates by 1 month.

I would just create a formula to increase the date from the previous sheet but the sheet another cell relies on the date cells. If I use a formula the cell that reads the date cells doesn't read it as a date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

I've tried using rangelist and doing either a for while or foreach loop but i only get it to list the date in the top cell for all the cells below.

I've changed my code so much I can't even get that to work again.

Edited:
This is what I have so far. I am able to copy the dates over into the next column but I don't know how to add a month to the dates.

```
function date() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet11');
  var date = new Date();
  var valuestocopy = sheet.getRange(1, 5, 25, 1);
  var copyto = sheet.getRange(1, 6, 25, 1);
 
sheet.getRange(copyto.getA1Notation()).setValue(date).setNumberFormat("M/D/YY");
copyto.setValues(valuestocopy.getValues());
}
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Comment: Just updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: I am able to get the values to copy their current value over with the last line of code. The line of codes second from the bottom just copies the first date and adds 1 month and pastes it down the whole column.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your showing script, you want to copy the values of "E1:E25" to "F1:F25". And, `I have a spreadsheet and I need to increase dates in the ranges 'G5:G27','T5:T27','AG5:AG27','AT5:AT27' by one month.` of your question is not related to your expected result. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes the end goal would be for the ranges 'G5:G27','T5:T27','AG5:AG27','AT5:AT27'. But I am practicing in a test sheet to see if I can do it in one column before I attempt severeal.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, in your question, what result do you want? For example, about `Yes the end goal would be for the ranges 'G5:G27','T5:T27','AG5:AG27','AT5:AT27'.`, in this case, what result do you want? And, about `But I am practicing in a test sheet to see if I can do it in one column before I attempt severeal.`, you want to include 2 questions in this question? I would like to create an answer by correctly understanding your question. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I added a photo to the post.
In the want to create a script to attach to a button. When the button is clicked, it updates all the dates + 1 month.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your added image, I cannot understand the relationship between `I have a spreadsheet and I need to increase dates in the ranges 'G5:G27','T5:T27','AG5:AG27','AT5:AT27' by one month.`, your showing script and your added image. And, what is your added image? Is that your expected input situation or your expected output situation? Can I ask you about the details of your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: I updated the photo.
I want the Button in the top left corner to have a script attached to it so when I click it. It increases all the dates by 1 month. So in this case they would all move to February.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand your question. I will prepare an answer. Please wait for it.

Comment: Thank so You!!!

Comment: I posted an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in the comment, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a sheet in Google Spreadsheet. The sheet has the date objects in the cells `'G5:G27','T5:T27','AG5:AG27','AT5:AT27'`.
- You want to add 1 month to all date objects in the cells.
- You want to run the script by clicking a button on the sheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this script, in order to reduce the process cost, Sheets API is used. So, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) before you run the script. And, please set your sheet name. And, please confirm your cell ranges of `a1Notation`.

In order to run this script by clicking a button on the sheet, please assign the function `date` to your button. By this, when you click the button, this script is run.

```js
function date() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  var a1Notations = ['G5:G27', 'T5:T27', 'AG5:AG27', 'AT5:AT27']; // This is from your question.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var ranges = a1Notations.map(e => `'${sheetName}'!${e}`);
  var { valueRanges } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges, valueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE" });
  var data = valueRanges.map(({ values }, i) => {
    var values = values.map(([v]) => {
      var unixTime = (v - 25569) * 86400 * 1000; // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953
      var temp = new Date(unixTime);
      temp.setMonth(temp.getMonth() + 1);
      var serialNumber = (temp.getTime() / 1000 / 86400) + 25569; // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953
      return [serialNumber];
    });
    return { range: ranges[i], values };
  });
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED" }, ssId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the cell values (date objects) are retrieved from `['G5:G27', 'T5:T27', 'AG5:AG27', 'AT5:AT27']`. And, 1 month is added to the values. And then, the updated values are put into the same range of `['G5:G27', 'T5:T27', 'AG5:AG27', 'AT5:AT27']`.

#### Note:

- As another approach, when you cannot use Sheets API, you can also use the following sample script.

  ```js
  function date() {
    var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
    var a1Notations = ['G5:G27', 'T5:T27', 'AG5:AG27', 'AT5:AT27']; // This is from your question.

    SpreadsheetApp
      .getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName(sheetName)
      .getRangeList(a1Notations)
      .getRanges()
      .forEach(r => {
        var values = r.getValues().map(([v]) => {
          v.setMonth(v.getMonth() + 1);
          return [v];
        });
        r.setValues(values);
      });
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you!
Unfortunately it gives the error " ReferenceError: Sheets is not defined
date @ Untitled 3.gs:8 "

Comment: @Riles Thank you for replying. About `Thank you! Unfortunately it gives the error " ReferenceError: Sheets is not defined dateChanger @ Untitled 3.gs:8 "`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I think that the reason for your this issue is due to that you have not enabled Sheets API at Advanced Google services. I have mentioned this in my answer. I apologize for this. So, please confirm it again. If you cannot understand this, how about testing my 2nd sample script? In that case, Sheets API is not used.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry about that. I didn't finish reading, I enabled Google Sheets API and it works perfectly!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Riles Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hello, Sorry I had another question about the script.
It works great the only thing is it enters a Timestamp after the date. Is there a way to not do this?

Comment: I also notice that for some dates only change by 30 days. For instance 10/1/2023 gets changed to 10/31/2023 instead of 11/1/2023.

Comment: @Riles About your new question, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by a comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77277156/apps-script-sheets-api-changing-month-by-1-also-adds-a-timestamp-in-the-cell-h

Here is the link to the new question. Thank you!

Comment: @Riles Thank you for your response. I commented on your new question. Please confirm it.