# Changing month by +1 also adds a timestamp in the cell. How do I not insert the timestamp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When I click the button "Change Dates" it updates the dates in the date column. It increases the dates by 1 month and inputs a Timestamp after the date. As you can see for the Date for Account 2 it increases the Date perfecting 1 month, but for Account 1 it increases it only 30 days from October 1st to October 31st.

I only want the month number to change and I don't want the timestamp inputted after the date.
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

```
function dateChanger() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet 1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  var a1Notations = ['G5:G27', 'T5:T27', 'AG5:AG27', 'AT5:AT27']; // This is from your question.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var ranges = a1Notations.map(e => `'${sheetName}'!${e}`);
  var { valueRanges } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges, valueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE" });
  var data = valueRanges.map(({ values }, i) => {
    var values = values.map(([v]) => {
      var unixTime = (v - 25569) * 86400 * 1000; // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953
      var temp = new Date(unixTime);
      temp.setMonth(temp.getMonth() + 1);
      var serialNumber = (temp.getTime() / 1000 / 86400) + 25569; // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953
      return [serialNumber];
    });
    return { range: ranges[i], values };
  });
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED" }, ssId);
}
```

I've tried to get rid of the unixTime and Serial Number variable but it doesn't work.

Comment: In your situation, in order to correctly replicate your current issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating it? Because when I tested your showing script to the value of "October 1st", "November 1st" was obtained. First, I would like to correctly replicate and confirm your situation.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pD0xbbcr-85gpZaCncIMx6Ho5sDA_nu0iFDKP3ZJvqo/edit?usp=sharing

Here is a link to a copy of the sheet

Comment: You will see the first two dates are fine but on most of them they now have a Timestamp

Comment: The main issue is you will see in the Table below Cells F32:AJ123 have the formula =IF(F$31=$G5,IFs($A5=TRUE,"",$A5=false,""),""). But with the time stamp in the Date this formula returns "".

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing a sample Spreadsheet. From your sample Spreadsheet and your showing script, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your provided Spreadsheet, the timezone offset might be related to your current issue. So, as one modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var data = valueRanges.map(({ values }, i) => {
  var values = values.map(([v]) => {
    var unixTime = (v - 25569) * 86400 * 1000; // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953
    var temp = new Date(unixTime);
    temp.setMonth(temp.getMonth() + 1);
    var serialNumber = (temp.getTime() / 1000 / 86400) + 25569; // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953
    return [serialNumber];
  });
  return { range: ranges[i], values };
});
```

#### To:

```
var data = valueRanges.map(({ values }, i) => {
  var values = values.map(([v]) => {
    var unixTime = (v - 25569) * 86400 * 1000; // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953
    var temp = new Date(unixTime);
    temp = new Date(unixTime + (temp.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)); // Added
    temp.setMonth(temp.getMonth() + 1);
    var serialNumber = ((temp.getTime() - (temp.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)) / 1000 / 86400) + 25569; // Modified Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953
    return [serialNumber];
  });
  return { range: ranges[i], values };
});
```

- When I tested this modification using your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that `10/1/23` is changed to `11/1/23`.

Comment: This worked perfectly !
Thank you so much for all your help. I'm not used to using Sheets API. I'm learning a lot analyzing this code!

Comment: @Riles Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.