# Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property batchUpdate on object Apiary.sheets.spreadsheets.values. Using SheetsAPI

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I've been using this code for months now and I never have any issues with it. I haven't even touched or edited my code.

I am using the Sheets API

Now all of a sudden I've been getting this error.[image]

Here is my code

```
function dateChanger() {

      var a1Notations = ['G5:G27', 'AC5:AC27', 'AR5:AR27', 'BG5:BG27']; 

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
      var ssId = ss.getId();
      var ranges = a1Notations.map(e => `'${sheetName}'!${e}`);
      var { valueRanges } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges, valueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE" });
      var data = valueRanges.map(({ values }, i) => {
      var values = values.map(([v]) => {
        var unixTime = (v - 25569) * 86400 * 1000; // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953
        var temp = new Date(unixTime);
        temp = new Date(unixTime + (temp.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)); // Added
        temp.setMonth(temp.getMonth() + 1);
        var serialNumber = ((temp.getTime() - (temp.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)) / 1000 / 86400) + 25569; // Modified Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953
        return [serialNumber];
      });
      return { range: ranges[i], values };
    });
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED" }, ssId);
    }
```

Comment: I think that in your situation, testing your showing script using a sample Spreadsheet will help think of the reason for your current issue. So, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue?