# How to get correct date with gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

How can I get the spreadsheet values with Python's gspread?

Suppose there is a cell that looks like 1/1 because m/d is specified as the cell display format, but actually contains 2024/1/1. Retrieving this cell using get_all_values() returns "1/1".
I want the actual value "2024/1/1", not the value displayed on the sheet.
What should I do?

[image]

I will omit the sheet acquisition part.

values = workbook.worksheet(sheet_name).get_all_values()

value = values[1][0] # 1/1 will be obtained

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your comment. I added it to the question.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. From your updated question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

From your showing image, script, and current value, I understood that you put a value of `2024/01/01` into a cell "A2" as a date object. And, the cell value is shown as `1/1` with the number format.

In the current stage, when this cell value is retrieved by Sheets API, `1/1` is retrieved as the default request of `valueRenderOption: FORMATTED_VALUE`. When `valueRenderOption` is changed to `UNFORMATTED_VALUE`, the serial number of `45292` is retrieved. Unfortunately, in the current stage, the inputted value of `2024/01/01` cannot be directly retrieved. So, it is required for the following flow.

1. Retrieve the serial number from a cell with `valueRenderOption: UNFORMATTED_VALUE`.
2. Convert the serial number to the date object.
3. Convert date format.

When this flow is reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
values = workbook.worksheet(sheet_name).get_all_values(value_render_option="UNFORMATTED_VALUE")
value = values[1][0]
date = datetime.fromtimestamp((int(value) - 25569) * 86400) # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953
formatted = date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') # or date.strftime('%Y/%-m/%-d')  # or date.strftime('%Y/%#m/%#d')
print(formatted)
```

- In the case that the cell "A2" has `2024/01/01` of the date object and `1/1` is shown by the number format, when this script is run, `formatted` is `2024/01/01`.
- `from datetime import datetime` is used.

#### References:

- [get_all_values](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v6.0.0/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.get_all_values)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.
When I corrected it and executed it, I was able to get 2024/1/1.
thank you very much!

Comment: @apricot Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. I added tags of `google-sheets` and `google-sheets-api`.